# Парсинг Json при помощи Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Как описать структуру классов для парсинга такой json-строки, приходящей от серверов вконтакте, используя Json.Net ?

```
{  
   "ts":1820350874,
   "updates":[  
      ­      [  
         4,
         1619489,
         561,
         123456,
         1464958914,
         " ... ",
         "hello",
         {  
            "attach1_type":"photo",
            "attach1":"123456_414233177",
            "attach2_type":"audio",
            "attach2":"123456_456239018"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

Пытался сделать через специальную вставку в Visual Studio - ругается на то, что некорректный Json.

Конвертировать всё в object'ы, и уже потом преобразовывать ?

В прошлый раз решил тем, что массив updates описал как List>, а когда нужно было достать значение - преобразовывал к конкретному типу.

Comment: http://www.json-generator.com  - используйте сайт.У вас проблема с json

Comment: Откуда вы вообще получаете невалидный json?

Comment: этот json приходит от longPoll сервера вконтакте. у них всегда всё через одно место, поэтому приходится что-то самостоятельно придумывать. А на в документации он употребляется в примере ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в Json Вам надо дать наименования всем полям, например вот так:

```
{
        "ts": "1820350874",
        "updates": {
            "number": 4,
            "number2": 1619489,
            "number3" : 561,
            "number4" : 123456,
            "number5": 1464958914,
            "dot": " ... ",
            "hello":"hello",
            "obj": {
                "attach1_type": "photo",
                "attach1": "123456_414233177",
                "attach2_type": "audio",
                "attach2": "123456_456239018"
            }

        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Для десериализации Json с неизвестными полями, попробуй использовать вот это:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
```

думаю, должно решить проблемы.

Comment: это я знаю, но дело в том, что количество и имя этих полей мне неизвестно, т.к. имён у них нет в принципе. Просто набор элементов в массиве. в прошлый раз решил тем, что создал List<List<object>> и в него парсил свой json

Comment: обновил ответ для парсинга неизвестных заранее данных

Comment: да просто у меня установлен Json.Net, хотел через него сделать всё. Так-то я мог бы и через UWP'шный парсер JSON'а сделать всё. В любом случае - спасибо, это помогло

Answer (score 0):

dynamic JSON = JObject.Parse(string js);

Затем можете работать с JSON так:
JSON["ts"]["updates"]

Данный способ лучше и легче